# Passing EditText to AsyncTask for URL

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-edittext

I'm new to Android; so please bear with me.
I'm trying to register a new user with Google Cloud Messasging. I got the "Register" button to work fine, using a tutorial. I'm trying to pass some EditText information into the same URL, username, password, etc.
RegisterApp.java looks like this

```
        package com.example.android.gcmtest;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.net.URISyntaxException;

    public class RegisterApp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private static final String TAG = "GCMRelated";
        Context ctx;
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
        String SENDER_ID = "mySenderID";
        String regid = null;
        private int appVersion;
        public RegisterApp(Context ctx, GoogleCloudMessaging gcm, int appVersion){
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.gcm = gcm;
            this.appVersion = appVersion;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(ctx);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                // is using accounts.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(ctx, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }

        private void storeRegistrationId(Context ctx, String regid) {
            final SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("registration_id", regid);
            editor.putInt("appVersion", appVersion);
            editor.commit();

        }



        private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
            URI url = null;
            try {

                url = new URI("http://192.168.0.21/gcm_server_php/register.php?regId=" + regid + "&myName=" + usernamevalue + "&myPassword=" + passwordvalue + "&myCredits=0");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(url);
            try {
                httpclient.execute(request);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Registration Completed. Continue to login...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v(TAG, result);
    }

}
```

My activity_main.xml looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<EditText
    android:text="username"
    android:id="@+id/myUserName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:text="password"
        android:id="@+id/myPassword"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register">
    </Button>"

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding

```
EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_simple);
String strValue = simpleEditText.getText().toString();
```

Displays 'cannot resolve method findviewbyid' 
I'm stuck... If you need to see MainActivity.java I'll happily post it.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.gcmtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private static final String TAG = "GCMRelated";
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    String regid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        final EditText myUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myUserName);
        String usernamevalue = myUsername.getText().toString();

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            regid = getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
            if(!regid.isEmpty()){
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }else{
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Check device for Play Services APK.
                if (checkPlayServices()) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    regid = getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());

                    if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        new RegisterApp(getApplicationContext(), gcm, getAppVersion(getApplicationContext())).execute();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device already Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
                }
            }
        });


    }


    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(getApplicationContext());
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your activity code !!

Comment: Where are you adding `EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_simple);`?

Comment: I added my activity code.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById` is function of `Activity`. I assume your `ctx` is `Activity`. so, as a quick and dirty solution:

```
EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) ((Activity)ctx).findViewById(R.id.et_simple);
String strValue = simpleEditText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I was really hopeful for Adem's post to work. However, the second I hit 'register' the app crashed. =/ the error is : runtime fatal exception: main

Comment: how do you use simpleEditText. I suspect you may try to set value in wrong function. for instance you can not call EditText.setValue from doInBackground

Comment: I have the code directly under:  public RegisterApp(Context ctx, GoogleCloudMessaging gcm, int appVersion){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.gcm = gcm;
        this.appVersion = appVersion;
    } I posted the code here.